# Flutter: Update a widget without using ValueKey

Tags: flutter

I have a widget (say "OrderScreen") that takes one parameter (say "order"), the problem is when I change the order, `OrderScreen` is not being updated. One way to fix this is to use `ValueKey` like so:

```dart
Order _order;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    child: OrderScreen(
      key: ValueKey(_order),
      order: _order
    ),
  );
}
```

but my issue is that I'm already using a key to access `OrderScreen` state:

```dart
final _orderScreenStateKey = GlobalKey<OrderScreenState>();
Order _order;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    child: OrderScreen(
      key: _orderScreenStateKey,
      order: _order
    ),
  );
}
```

Is there a way to say Flutter to update this widget every time I change `_order`?

Comment: post `OrderScreen` code, is it custom `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: Will `_order` be used only in one widget?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it's a stateful widget.

Comment: @HasanAlyazidi Yes, in one widget.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you need to access `_order` data in other widgets, you might want to take a look at [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Provider will allow you to manage the state across widgets fairly easily.

A good video overview of it can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update every time you change the `_order`, and the action is in the same class as the widget.

```
setState(() {
  this._order = _newOrder;
});
```

The `setState` will rebuild the widget with the new value.